# Dynamic Super Resolution

Tags: c++, opengl, nvidia, nvapi

Is there a way to turn on/off DSR setting using NVAPI? I couldn't find any setting ID in *NvApiDriverSettings.h* file that would correspond to Dynamic Super Resolution setting in NVIDIA Control Panel.